# Waiting for success of Jquery.trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that has a set of drill-downs so one drop down will fill in another. I have a script set up to remember the form values and reset them for that page. My issue comes in when I execute on the trigger for the element, I can't figure out any way to wait on the other dropdown to refresh and then setting its value. Is there any way I can wait for the success result of a function that's kicked off by `trigger('change')` (or similar function) besides listening for the ajax request. My fall back plan is to do this with cookies and then fill in the form server side. Which might look better anyway, I'm just wondering if it can be done.

I have it saving the values from each drop down and loading them when I get back, I'm wondering if there's some way I can
listen for the ajax call in dropdown_a to finish if I load the value from session storage and call $('#dropdown_a').trigger('change')
the more I think about it I'd probably have to store some sort of value in the program that tracks any request made so I can await them
which would defeat the purposes of the self contained script I have for this

```js
$('#dropdown_a').on('change', function() {
 //Ajax call I want to wait for
 $.ajax({
  url: 'someendpoint',
  data: 1,
  success: function(response) {
   util.fillsInSelectBox(response, $('#dropdown_b'));
  },
  error: function() {
   showErrorModal();
  }
 });
});

$('#dropdown_b').on('change', function() {
 $('#table').bootstrapTable('refresh');
});
```

Comment: What is the difference when a drop down is "refreshed" ? Can you give us a more useful code example? My initial thinking is that you could create a chain of functions that would set each other off, if not by async callback, then by intervals(recursive checking).

Comment: *"besides listening for the ajax request"* : you *should* listen to the ajax request.

Comment: Also, what @trincot said. Even if you're not explicitly using AJAX calls and syntax that's essentially what you'd be mimicking. Not sure if you have a reason for that but if you do I'd be very surprised if it justified not using already built methods.

Comment: Would it not make logical sense to make that a part of the fillsInSelectBox method?  Inside that method, if the dropdown has a value, save it in a variable, rebuild the select, and then set the value back if possible.  Otherwise if no value present at the start, skip the restoration.  Optionally pass in an option if you want to wipe out the existing value.

Comment: @Taplar That's the first approach we took, which does work, I'm just trying to work out a more generic solution. I think the only way to really do it generically is to save it into a cookie and read it server side the more I think about it. I've had it set up before for more static forms where it just loads and unloads, but I think in this case it's not really something I can do, at least easily since I have to wait on network request.

Comment: So you feel that basing the restoration off of whatever, possibly random, select element you give fillsInSelectBox to work with, you think it is more generic to specify a specific cookie or storage variable you have to keep track of to go with some specific dropdown?